# What means 你跟以前一样的是 sentence？

Tags: meaning

I understand this design, but I saw such a case . I do not understand why  is 是 at the end of the sentence . Can you explain please

Answer (score 1):

Random chunks of language, without context, are difficult to fathom. You should post the context where you found this scrap of language, at least the sentence before and the sentence after.

Unless one is a René Descartes (je pense donc je suis) one is hardly likely to go around saying "你是。", but in the right context, a lonely “你是。” may be enough said。

你跟以前一样的是 ？？？

你跟以前一样的是你永远都会迟到！
You haven't changed, you still always come late!

两年不见，
Two years (we have) not seen each other,
没想到他变化这么大，
I wouldn't have thought he'd have changed so much,
比以前瘦了很多，
(he's) a lot thinner than before,
但和以前一样的是，
but (what) hasn't changed is,
他还是那么热情、快乐、关心别人
he is still friendly, happy and concerned about others.

和以前一样的**是** --> [他还是那么热情、快乐、关心别人.]

Comment: I can not understand why it is used here 两年不见，没想到他变化这么大，比以前瘦了很多，但和以前一样的是， 
他还是那么热情、快乐、关心别人

Answer (score 1):

你跟以前一樣的是你的眼神。Literal Translation: What you are the same as before is your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

It connects two phrases:

- 你跟以前一样的**是**我心目中的英雄. - You, as always, **are** a hero in my mind, or, You, Like before, **are** a hero in my mind.

Similar sentence with the same pattern:

- 我最喜歡他的**是**他的誠挚 - I like him the most **is** his sincerity.
- 我曾經热愛過的**是**足球 - The thing I loved **was** soccer.

Answer (score 0):

The basic sentence with all details stripped away is 你是， "you are".  跟以前一样 is adding detail saying "as before/ as usual".

的 connects the detail phrase to the basic sentence. So the total sentence would mean "You are the same as always/usual/etc".

In this case 是 is not serving as any kind of grammatical accent, but just as the basic definition-- an equivalent to english am/is/are. The reason its at the end of the sentence is just a coincidence of it being the only character in the predicate/verb area this time.